# WaitForMultipleObjects crashes on 64bit windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, 64-bit

Consider the code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < thread_number; i ++)
    hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread( 
            0,                   
            0,                      
            single_thread_function_name,      
            (LPVOID)i,                      
            0,                      
            &dwThreadIdArray[i]);   


WaitForMultipleObjects(thread_number, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

It works correctly on 32 bit platform, but on 64 bit it crashes.

The crash happens in the WaitForMultipleObjects function.

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Edit:
hThreadArray is declared as:

```
HANDLE*  hThreadArray;
hThreadArray = (HANDLE*) malloc (thread_number * sizeof(HANDLE));
```

The single_thread_function_name as:

```
DWORD WINAPI single_thread_function_name( LPVOID lpParam ){
.....
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `hThreadArray` and the code for `single_thread_function_name()`?

Comment: And did you store anything in hThreadArray, or did you leave it uninitialized?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it crashes"? What is the value of `thread_number`? Is it larger than `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`? Can you provide a complete program that fails. Strip out all the unneeded stuff.

Comment: DavidHeffernan: the value of thread_number is 2, statically assigned.

@bmargulies: I allocate the memory space but i don't initialize the hThreadArray array. Is it wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible piece of code? This is looking fine from here (but i haven't done this in a while).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hThreadArray is not an array, just a pointer, it certainly should crash. It is strange how it works on 32-bit platform.

As hThreadArray is malloced, maybe it does not meet 64-bit alignment requirements. Try with:

```
HANDLE hThreadArray[100] = {0};
```

Comment: An array name is a pointer to the first element of the array. Without the initialization of `hThreadArray`, you cannot say that it is not an array.

Comment: Yes, i initialize it in this way:
hThreadArray = (HANDLE*) malloc (thread_number * sizeof(HANDLE));

It's an array.

Comment: "Maybe it does not meet 64-bit alignment requirements." That's an excellent suggestion. Using `new[]` rather than vile C `malloc` would also ensure alignment requirements were appropriate.

Comment: Alignment - bet that's it, (no actual cash...).

Comment: The problem was that the single_thread_funcion uses malloc; dubling the size of the malloc solved the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: @Default: Before the question edit, There was just the "HANDLE* hThreadArray;" line, there was no malloc line or some other initialization...

Comment: @Aslan986: I do not understand how doubling the size of malloc solved your problem , can you enlighten us ?